# ViewPager in navigation drawer - Please give some advice

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation

So overall idea is to in first (main page) have swiping gallery and I did it BUT when I choose options from navigation menu I'm having **pager layout** witch is my navigation drawer layout and its blank cuz just contain **android.support.v4.view.ViewPager**

CONTENT_MAIN.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/pager"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.marcj.justtest.drawer"
>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

But now I want to go to my navigation drawer choose on of the options there and have OTHER swiping gallery.. but I don't know How to do it because when I choose option for example **SOLD** I'm having blank layout.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQyZo.jpg)

drawer.java file:

```
package com.example.marcj.justtest;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class drawer extends AppCompatActivity implements         
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PageAdapter padapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(padapter);





    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,             
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
 findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("username");

    TextView text2 = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.TVusername);
    text2.setText(username);



}








@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;

    } else if (id == R.id.action_contact) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Contact Form", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        Intent i = new Intent(drawer.this, AcContact.class);
        startActivity(i);

        contact contactForm = new contact();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager,
                contactForm, contactForm.getTag()).commit();

    }   else if (id == R.id.nav_clicked) {
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_homepage) {

        Intent i= new Intent (drawer.this, drawer.class );
        startActivity(i);

} else if (id == R.id.nav_clicked) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        clicked clickedItems = new clicked();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager,
                clickedItems, clickedItems.getTag()).commit();


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_won) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Won Items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        won wonItems = new won();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager,
                wonItems, wonItems.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_selling) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item that you Selling", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        selling sellingItems = new selling();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager,
                sellingItems, sellingItems.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_sold) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sold Items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        sold soldItems = new sold();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager,
                soldItems, soldItems.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_topup) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Top-Up Clicks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        topup topupItems = new topup();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager,
                topupItems, topupItems.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {





    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
   }
 }
```

PageAdapter.java

```
package com.example.marcj.justtest;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public PageAdapter (FragmentManager fm){

    super(fm);
}

public Fragment getItem (int arg0){

    switch (arg0){

        case 0:
            return new FragmentOne();

        case 1:
            return new FragmentTwo();

        case 2:
            return new FragmentThree();


        default:
            break;
    }

    return null;
}



public int getCount(){

    return 3;
}
}
```

Activity_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".drawer">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Please post you activity_drawer.xml file.

Comment: any ideas? :) @ManiKandanSelvanathan

Answer (score 0):

**activity_drawer file:**

```
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_drawer_menu" />
```

**content_main**

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/pager"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.marcj.justtest.drawer"
>
```